Using "no" at the end of a statement instead of "isn't it"?
Something I have observed on "Indian twitter" is using "no" instead of "isn't it"; for e.g.

The phone is very expensive, no?

instead of

This phone is very expensive, isn't it?

Is it even correct/idiomatic? I don't think I have observed it anywhere else, granted I don't have much experience in that regard.
Is there any reason why this usage is so prominent in Indian English? I do remember it being mentioned, in some blog, as one of "features" of Indian English.

I will note that using isn't it?  as an all-purpose tag question, e.g. You're running late, isn't it? is also known as a distinctly 'Indian' thing.

@MichaelHarvey It should be aren't you, right?

Sahil, yes, that is correct.

@MichaelHarvey There's also the British version innit which can be used regardless of subject, number, etc.

A small nitpick, something is only not correct if it’s unintelligible.

The key point of using "isn't it" or "innit" is that it doesn't focus on you (who is running late), it focuses on the fact (that you're running late). Consider that this is the equivalent of asking "isn't it true that you're running late?" rather than "are you running late?"

@MichaelHarvey - it's also a Welsh thing, I believe. It's fairly common amongst Welsh people to add tags to the ends of sentences, "isn't it?" being quite common.

@Spratty - mae hynny'n iawn fy nghariad!

@MichaelHarvey - please accept my apologies in advance but that looks very much like something a Lovecraft character would shout when trying to summon Yog Sothoth or Cthulu :-D

@Spratty - according to Google Translate, it's Welsh for 'that's right my love!'

@MichaelHarvey Why do Indians insist on using the incorrect version? I am sorry if that is insensitive. I am genuinely curious, and can't think of any other way of saying it.

I think the most idiomatic way to say this in American English is "Right?", but I do think "No?" and "Yeah?" are also used by some native speakers.

For native British standard English speakers, using 'no?' as a 'tag question' would be understood readily, but is not idiomatic. It is often seen as a sign that the speaker is not themselves a native speaker, or possibly using an eccentric affectation. A number of European languages (e.g. French, Spanish, Italian) do use 'no?', 'non?' as normal, idiomatic tag questions, so that such an utterance in English is a cliché of 'foreign-ness', e.g. in lazily written novels.
According to @TimR,

The "no" tag is heard in American English but it's not used
colloquially. It is in much the same register as "is that not so?"
though it is more easygoing. "Mr Jones, you've testified before this
committee in the past, no?" The questioner is not treating Mr Jones as
a hostile witness.


The "no" tag is heard in American English but it's not used colloquially. It is in much the same register as "is that not so?" though it is more easygoing.  "Mr Jones, you've testified before this committee in the past, no?"  The questioner is not treating Mr Jones as a hostile witness.

In AmE, more common tag questions are "Right?" or "Yeah?" or even "Yes?" (for a more formal version). I agree that in AmE "no?" frequently (although not always) signals foreign-ness or a specific cultural identity. There are some stereotypes of particular ethnic groups (Italian Americans come to mind) who use "No?".

@FriendlyRacoon - I had an extremely irritating colleague here in the UK who ended just about every sentence with 'OK, yeah?'.

@MichaelHarvey I noticed a british airport staff person talking like this "you are going to canada, yeah?" at Heathrow airport. Basically, every thing he said ended with "yeah?". That was my first and only time in UK (technically). I found that very interesting. I have noticed the same thing(on the internet) with Canadians with 'eh?', but I am not entirely sure if they both are alike?

@Sahil , I think they are pretty alike, and you may find this article interesting. My former colleague's use of 'OK yeah?' sounds very like the 'narrative use' mentioned there.

So is it at least to some degree idiomatic in American English? According to TimR, the expression is used, albeit in a narrow context, while according to Friendly Racoon it "signals foreign-ness". These statements mostly don't contradict each other (it's heard in formal context AND it's interpreted as "foreignish" in a colloquial context), but I'm curious to hear more opinions on this.

I wouldn't regard "no?" to seek feedback after a statement as being at all strange or foreign-sounding, any more than "ok?", "right?", or "yes?". "You said you were on holiday, yes?".

I wouldn’t consider it unidiomatic either. Less common than ‘yeah?’ or ‘right?’, more colloquial than ‘yes?’ (but less than ‘innit?’), but still common enough among native speakers that it would sound at all foreign to me. I have on occasion heard Spanish speakers use ‘not?’ instead of ‘no?’, which is distinctly foreign and unidiomatic, but ‘no?’ has no such connotations to me at all.

Germans might use "or not?" for the word by word translation of "oder nicht?"

I find it fascinating that using both ", yes?" and ", no?" at the end of a sentence like that means exactly the same thing.

@David Words that mean their opposites in certain contexts are so confusing! As a 40-year-old native English speaker, I still don't know whether making the air conditioning colder is called "turning the AC up" or "down" :-D

@yshavit you turn the AC down to make it colder since the lower the temperature the colder it is. You turn it up to increase the temperature.

@David ", there is a subtle difference between ", yes?" and ", no?". You use ", yes?" with an assumed positive conclusion, you already arrived at but seeking a confirmation that your "positive" assumption was in fact correct. Similarly, ", no?" is the negative conclusion you made in your mind but seeking further confirmation that your assumption was in fact true i.e. a negative confirmation.

@codejockie but turning down the AC can also mean "make it work less", which means it's going to be warmer. It's an ambiguity my friends and I have all recognized, so even if you've picked one canonical answer for yourself, be aware the person you're talking to may have a different one. ;)

@yshavit you are right my friend. It gets confusing when you look at it that way.

This question was also asked on the English SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67710/is-it-correct-to-append-no-to-a-question#67711
The most upvoted answers there view it as a grammatical, but slightly uncommon equivalent to "isn't it?", which matches my experience as a native AmE speaker in various parts of the Eastern and Midwestern US. "You went to the store, no?" has the same meaning as "You went to the store, didn't you?" to me, although the "no" version is perhaps a little friendlier and less accusatory. Both of them imply the person being addressed did not actually go to the store despite some expectation that they would.
Several people in the other question do describe "no?" as sounding foreign or being associated with certain groups. I don't share that association and not all the answers there mentioned it, so it's possible that the "foreignness" association is either generational or regional. I've used it plenty of times myself and have heard it from other native speakers.

Sorry, but I have to agree with those who said that "..., no?" sounds 'foreign', and I would largely assume the speaker was European, rather than American or Indian.

@MikeB - Disagree. I heard it a fair bit when I was younger. I wish I had a good way to Google or ngram it. I think you would find there are certain contexts in AmE it is (or was) quite common. I can't quite put my mental finger on it, but none of the localization speculations in that answer are doing it for me.

I just watched an episode of The Young Turks on YouTube, and Ana Kasparian used "no?" as a question tag (at about 9:53).  She's American, and it sounded perfectly idiomatic when she said it.

I think it's perhaps a slight affectation. English speakers get bored and move words around.
As a Canadian, it's a bit reminiscent of adding "n'est-ce pas?" ("isn't it?" in French) at the end of a sentence.

Don't French speakers sometimes end with "..., non?"

@paddotk Sadly, I am not fluent, nor exposed regularly to, either Quebecois or Parisian French (or any other kind of French), other than the backside of soup cans and such like.

I don't understand your second sentence then. It suggests that you are familiair with French.
